# Java, Collectors.toList() creates only one element

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I am having troubles getting the following to work. The point of this task is to use streams:

```
Map<String, List<String>> descriptions = new HashMap<>();
wordArray[2] = "D1_E1^E2^E3^E4~D2_E1^E2";
if(wordArray[2].contains("~")) {
    Arrays.stream(wordArray[2].split("~"))
            .forEach(s -> descriptions.put(s.split("_")[0],
                   s.split("_")[1].contains("^")
                           ? Arrays.stream(s.split("_")[1].split("^"))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()) 
                               : Arrays.asList(s.split("_")[1])));
}
```

For some reason this Collectors.toList() creates only one String `"E1^E2^E3^E4"` instead of seperate Strings. 
My guess is that this is where I'm wrong : `Arrays.stream(s.split("_")[1].split("^"))`, but I don't know where exactly and how to fix it. More so because this works just fine and is quite similar to the one above:

```
List<String> synonyms = new ArrayList<>(); 
wordArray[3] = "S1_S2_S3_S4";
synonyms = wordArray[3].contains("_")
                            ? Arrays.stream(wordArray[3].split("_")).
                                  collect(Collectors.toList())
                            : Arrays.asList(wordArray[3]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `split()` parameter is a regular expression, and `^` is a special matching pattern for matching the beginning of the string. To split on `^`, escape it, i.e. `split("\\^")`. --- However, calling `split()` with something that doesn't exists in the input, i.e. when `contains()` return false, will just return a one-element array with the entire input. The `contains()` call is a waste of time.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Andreas, thank you, that was the problem! Also, it works just fine without the `contains()` call, so thanks for that tip as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your expected output should be, but if it's something like this

> [D1, E1, E2, E3, E4, D2, E1, E2]

then one of the way you can do it with Java streams is:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "D1_E1^E2^E3^E4~D2_E1^E2";
        List<String> strings = Parser.parseString(str);
        System.out.println(strings);
    }

    public static List<String> parseString(String str) {
        return Stream.of(str)
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[_^~]", "-").split("-"))
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

From here you can factor out the regex and pass it into parseString as second argument to have more flexibility (if needed).

Comment: The Stream API isn't needed to achieve the string processing which you perform.

Comment: Of course not,  but as stated in his question "The point of this task is to use streams", he was asking for stream approach.

Comment: Without streams: `return Arrays.asList(str.split("[_^~]"));`